# How to block a user from seeing a page in Java EE

Tags: security, authentication, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I am new to Java EE and I am developing an application which should provide different services to logged in and logged out user.

Do you guys know how I can use the web.xml to define a logged in and a logged out user and specify which pages they can see?

Also, I will need to redirect a non logged in user to the home page when he tries to access certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's a standard Java EE feature. Just read up on defining security constraints in web.xml. To start, you probably want to take a look at form-based security. [The official Oracle Java EE 6 tutorial is a good place to start with](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html).